# How can i write an JSON file with PHP which looks like this (nested JSON structure)?

Tags: php, json

I want to write an "nested" JSON structure with PHP Have a look below how the result should look like:

(Manually written -can read in JS without errors :) )

```
{
    "general": {
        "language": "English",
        "workingmode": "Normal"
    },
    "scene": [{
          "id": 0,
          "calendar_event": "urlaub",
          "element": [
              {
              "device": "boiler1",
              "active_state": "nothing",
              "hybernation_state": "off",
              "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
              },
              {
              "device": "boiler1",
              "active_state": "on",
              "hybernation_state": "off",
              "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
              }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "calendar_event": "urlaub",
          "element": [
              {
              "device": "boiler1",
              "active_state": "on",
              "hybernation_state": "off",
              "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
              },
              {
              "device": "boiler1",
              "active_state": "on",
              "hybernation_state": "off",
              "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
              }
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
$knxGenSet = (object) [
    'general' => (object) [],
    'scene' => []

    //Now i Struggle with this part, i cannot accomplish it to add "element" so that it is nested inside of "scene"
];

//creating structure for "general"
$knxGenSet->general->language = $_POST["langsetts"];
$knxGenSet->general->workingmode = $_POST["wmodesetts"];

//second part which i struggle with
  $knxGenSet->scene[] = (object) [
      //creating structure for "scene"
      'id' => 0,
      'calendar_event' => "anything"
      //Struggle: cannot get it right to add "element"-array which consists of 4 more String to the structure
  ];
```

I did manage to add the "general" tab and an part of "scene" but what i didn't manage to do is to add the part of "element"-array to the "scene"

btw i can allready read this json format with JS

Thanks in advance (kind of newb on json territory! :()

Comment: where is the element data going to come from? What structure does it have? We can't tell you how to put it in your object if we don't know what it looks like before it goes in there.

Comment: Element data can be just any string. I will try and update my question for better understandability now. Thanks!

Comment: "just any string"...but in your JSON example it's an array of objects, so it can't just start as a single string, surely?

Comment: "I didn't manage to do it thus I didnt add my "code""...that's not really how this site should work. Normally you show what you've tried, and we help you to fix specific bits of it, rather than just writing the whole thing from the start. It's generally easier that way (and also it helps to prove that the person asking is not just a freeloader looking to get their work done without having to make any effort)

Comment: I tought u were asking for the input. I have added an manually written JSON structure I want to acomplish that structure now programatically (The reading part of that manually written json structure works fine :) )

Comment: I know what you mean. I will clarify my question now & add some more code which I have tried

Comment: "I want to acomplish that structure now programatically"...yes, but based on what? For the rest of the data, you've shown where it comes from (e.g. $_POST variables). But for this "element" data we have no idea what the input is. So yes, I want the input, but all you told me was that it's some kind of string. That's not enough info. Examples would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing some minor key points

```
$knxGenSet = (object) [
    'general' => (object) ["language" => $_POST["langsetts"], 
    "workingmode" => $_POST["wmodesetts"]
]
];

for($j=0; $j<2; $j++) {
    $scene = (object) [
        'id' => $j,
        'calendar_event' => $_POST["calendarevent" . $j]
    ];

    for($ii=0; $ii<2; $ii++) {
        $scene->element[] = (object) [
            "device" => "boiler".$ii,
            "active_state"=> "on",
            "hybernation_state"=> "off",
            "calendar_name"=> "roomlink4"
         ];
    }
    $knxGenSet->scene[] = $scene;
}

print json_encode($knxGenSet);
```

**output**

```
{
    "general": {
        "language": null,
        "workingmode": null
    },
    "scene": [{
        "id": 0,
        "calendar_event": null,
        "element": [{
            "device": "boiler0",
            "active_state": "on",
            "hybernation_state": "off",
            "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
        }, {
            "device": "boiler1",
            "active_state": "on",
            "hybernation_state": "off",
            "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "calendar_event": null,
        "element": [{
            "device": "boiler0",
            "active_state": "on",
            "hybernation_state": "off",
            "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
        }, {
            "device": "boiler1",
            "active_state": "on",
            "hybernation_state": "off",
            "calendar_name": "roomlink4"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much after some adapting to my code it's working like an charm !!! :))

Comment: sorry i forgot to do so. I did now!